# Change text from dynamic jquery object not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got the following issue.

I am generating some objects (DIV boxes) with some text using jquery and assigning a unique ID to them.

When you click them, they should change their text, BUT the problem is that apparently because they were just created in the view/screen, jquery or js cannot make the change by using the text() function.

So... if you refresh the screen, those objects will be grabbed from the DB and then you can click them fine.

Any recommendation?

Marco

Comment: Take a look at [jquery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Specifically the `selector` portion of the docs.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Guys, I think that I am closer right now. I checked the delegate and on, all those are on at the end! LOL, but those are triggered by "events", in my case - You click the div, it will run an ajax post, when the data return I validate the output and then I change the text, so I need to run like a regular $ ( "#mydiv" ).html('data from ajax') , I don't have such thing like a click!

Comment: Thanks for the information, ON did the trick here, and changing the way my ajax script was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html(), take a look to this:

```js
$(document).on('click','#div1',function(){
 $("#div1").html('Change Div 1');
});
$(document).on('click','#div2',function(){
 $("#div2").html('Change Div 2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Please let me know if works for you.

Comment: Juan, thanks for the comment! my issue if with the object activation, as it wasn't loaded by the page and instead it was dynamically inserted to the DOM I need to use .on, or .delegate, .live(Not working for me. 1.9)!, but I don't have any event to trigger the event itself.

Comment: Juan, after reading and actually understanding what all those on, delagate, etc do ... I was able to make it work, needed to wrap some results in functions, and catch them with the very first line that you put. Thank you so much.